# email MIME Content-Disposition hyperlink

Tags: python, mime

Hi i an building an mbox file from a db blob and would like to add an hyperlink to the Attachement header

I am building the header like this

```
msg=email.message_from_string(blob)
msg["Content-Disposition"]="attachment; filename=filename.txt;"
```

What do i need to add to add a http or ftp hyperlink for the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attachment is MIME encoded along with the message, you can't have an http/ftp hyperlink, because the file does not reside on any FTP or HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do what you want.  Look at Section 7.3.3 in RFC 1521, which defines the `external-body` subytpe:

```
Content-Type: message/external-body;
           name="logo.png";
           site="ftp.example.com";
           access-type=ANON-FTP;
           directory="pub";
           mode="image";
           expiration="Fri, 13 Jun 2013 19:13:15 -0400 (EDT)"
```

It allows data to be pulled from a variety of external sources.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt